# Создать метки apache-poi и xmlbeans

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, создание-метки

В последнее время работаю с библиотекой apache - poi и вот когда ищу по меткам в RUSO немного не удобно от того что нету меток apache-poi и xmlbeans.

Добавьте метки [apache-poi](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-poi) и [xmlbeans](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xmlbeans), у меня рейтинга нет, чтобы это сделать.

Comment: Хоть бы сказал, куда их добавить...

Comment: RUSO у меня не хватает репутации добавлять новые метки

Comment: Я умею читать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы обосновать необходимость метки, предоставьте:

1. Примеры вопросов, на которых эта метка была бы релевантна. Хотя бы по одному. Надо же нам где-то создавать эту метку.
2. Текст хотя бы краткого описания метки, а лучше и полного пару абзацев. Так можно будет создать сразу хорошо оформленную метку, которую будут использовать в новых вопросах.

Кстати, только от того, что метка будет создана, она не появится автоматически на всех вопросах, которые касаются предмета метки. Кому-то нужно будет профильтровать массу вопросов из поиска по ключевым словам, выделить подходящие вопросы и добавить к ним метку. Вы могли бы этим заняться?

Для справки: те же метки на En.SO:

- [apache-poi](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/apache-poi/info)
- [xmlbeans](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlbeans/info)

Comment: да с радостью занялся бы

Comment: @AslanKussein: отлично. Тогда дайте хоть по одному вопросу, которые точно по теме этих меток.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446710/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-java-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-xml-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-xmlbeans

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446661/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B8%D0%B7-xml-%D0%B2-ms-word

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/442903/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%81-xml

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159231/apache-poi-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5-word

Comment: и таких много там в метках стоит apache но было бы намного проще если бы там было apache-poi!!!

Comment: @AslanKussein: создал обе метки по разу. Дальше вы их сможете добавлять самостоятельно. На своих вопросах — сразу, на чужих — правка пройдет проверку сначала.

Comment: только один про XMLbeans

Comment: @AslanKussein: я имею в виду вопросы, где метка [tag:apache], а должна быть [tag:apache-poi]? Уверен, что далеко не везде нужна такая замена. Я вам предлагаю пока что ставить на своих вопросах эти метки, а еще сделать для них хорошие описания. Тогда станет понятно, что ими отмечать, а что — нет.

Comment: просто было бы намного проще искать по метке если была бы метка [apache-poi]

Comment: @AslanKussein: почитайте на Мете и в Справке про то, что должно быть в описаниях меток. Можно перевести с английского (ссылки в ответе). Только из Википедии не надо копировать определения ))